# how to change widget name at runtime in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a label which i need to create as per the size of my record 
like if there are 2 records from database , my method should check and create 2 new labels at runtime , if 10 records there should be 10 labels to be created at run time 
I am able to create 10 new labels at run time but how can i name them differently

some thing like

```
                 for (int i =0;i<array.size();i++)
                  {
                      Label lbl = new Label();
                  }
```

in this way there are 10 labels and showing perfectly , but all ten have the same name i.e lbl can this name could also be change  like  lbl1,lbl2,lbl3...
is it possible in GWT

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you want to do isn't poosible in any programming language.

The solution you are searching for is storing them inside a list and then access the labels via the index. Eg. if you want the first label you say List[0]

GWT supports such list, the easiast for you to use ist the ArrayList!

here is some more or less pseudo code:

```
    ArrayList<Label> labelList = new ArrayList<Label>();
    for (int i =0;i<array.size();i++)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        labelList.add(lbl);
    }

    ...

    //the first item has the index 0!
    Label lbl1 = labelList.get(0);
    ..
    //doing stuff with the first label
    ...
    //getting the secont label
    Label lbl2 = labelList.get(1);

    ...
    //you get the idea right
    ...
```